# Title for bounty FAQ item

Tags: feature-request

The title "What if I don't get an answer?" does not bring "bounty" to mind. I saw bounties from using Stack Overflow and was interested to learn more. I tried looking in the FAQ but didn't find anything and eventually did a google search which is how I found out that "What if I don't get an answer?" is the question for bounties. Perhaps putting "(bounty)" or "(bounties)" after the question would help the title be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that part of the FAQ is not about bounties, but how to get an answer when you didn't get an answer already. Offering a bounty is the last try, when everything else have been already tried; it's not the first thing you should do when a question is left without an answer.

If you want to get more information about bounties, you can look for [bounties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=bounties&submit=search), or [bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=bounty&submit=search) on this very site.

Comment: While technically correct, the question does however explain most of the specifics of how bounties work. At most 20% (in terms of screen height) of the question answers topics other than bounties. It explains when a bounty can be given, what amounts can be given, what the duration is, etc, etc, etc.